# ¿Cómo recuperar contraseña de el formulario que hice para un Login de mi App con Firebase Auth?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

Resulta que he creado un login normal donde te registras y entras, o te logeas mediante el email y pass creado anteriormente y entras.

Utilizo la libreria de Firebase Auth para que sea lo mas seguro posible.

El asunto es como utilizar el "parametro hash de contraseña", para hacer mi App mejor y más segura.

Gracias

Comment: ¿ porque no agregas el código? Revisar [ask].

Comment: Claro, pero en donde en que parte del programa, o en algun editor de texto?